# psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "your name" does not exist

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2

When I try to upload the `PlayerScore` with the code

```
if Number.PlayerScore > Score.interact_database("SELECT Score FROM score WHERE Name = %s;" % Player_Name, False,)[0][0]
```

to the PostgreSQL Database in Python I get this error: `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "your name" does not exist` , where 'your name' is the variable Player_Name. However, when I run it in the PostgreSQL Query Tool it works fine. Does anyone know why this errors pops up and how I can prevent it from happening again in the future?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters

I think we'd need to see more of the code, but as per the docs:

> Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint.

Try passing the parameters as the second argument in your cursor.execute() method. Using something like:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT Score FROM score WHERE Name = %(player)s""", {'player': player_name } )
cursor.fetchone()
```

Should work. It can also accept a tuple of values.